# How to return ajax call in new window after calling partial view (mvc)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
$('#ResultDiv').html(result);
```

instead of printing the result in html tag, i want to print the result in new window

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { Employeeid: Employeeidv },
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadContentInfo","Home")',
    success: function (result) {
        //print result in new window
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { Employeeid: Employeeidv },
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadContentInfo","Home")',
    success: function (result) {
        //print result in new window
        var w = window.open();
        $(w.document.body).html(result);
    }
});
```

Of course browsers configured to block intempestive opening of popups will block all this illegal activity. Personally I would have implemented this using some sort of modals (like [`bootstrap modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)) instead of trying to open new browser windows.

Comment: `@praguan` Did it not resolve your issue? I think response from `@DarinDimitrov` should be marked as an answer - unless I'm missing something here. It works for me. Marking as an Answer will help other users (like myself), as well. Again if something missing here you may want to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { Employeeid: Employeeidv },
    url: '@Url.Action("LoadContentInfo","Home")',
    success: function (result) {
       //Open url in new window
       window.open("http://yourUrl/", "MyWindow", "height=300,width=300");
}
```

If you want to open in new tab:

```
window.open("http://yourUrl", "_blank", "width=600,height=500");
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller has a method to return the PartialView:

```
 public PartialViewResult CreatePartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("MyPartialView");
    }
```

The MyPartialView code looks like this:

```
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>
        This is a very nice web page.
    </p>
<button id="NewBrowserBtn">New Browser</button>
```

Now for the magic that makes it happen using window.open:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#NewBrowserBtn').on('click', function () {
        window.open('/Home/CreatePartialView', '_blank', 'left=100,top=100,width=400,height=300,toolbar=1,resizable=0');
    });
});
```